# How to resolve warning

Tags: c#, generics

I have:

> Warning Type parameter 'TFrom' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type

```
     private class InnerExpressionTransformer<TFrom, TTo> : ExpressionVisitor
        where TTo : TFrom
    {
        private ParameterExpression _parameter;

        public InnerExpressionTransformer()
        {
            _parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTo));
        }
    }
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Either rename the parameters in the inside class, or remove the generic type parameters if you're supposed to follow the outer class.

Comment: Is this class inside another class? Can you post any other relevant code that contains `TFrom`?

Comment: Are you sure you need your `InnerExpressionTransformer` type to be generic at all? It sounds like it's already nested within a generic type... it's hard to help with no clue as to what you're trying to achieve, but try just making it not generic...

Comment: You are going to have to post your outer class (this has to be an inner one, otherwise `private` doesn't make much sense). The only real fix is to rename the inner type as @LasseV.Karlsen says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning states, you have a type parameter with the same name. This is a warning because nested classes share the generic paraneters of their parent type - you must reference `Outer<Paraneter>.Inner`. Because of this, the names can collide, and because of that, any usage of that type parameter will use the inner definition, thus hiding the outer parameter. While this might be intended behaviour, it could result in a nasty gotcha should you try to reference the outer.

There are two way to resolve this, the first and foremost being to make sure you *need* that inner type. If you're simply restating the outer generic, it's completely unnecessary, and can be done away with; even constraints such as `TTo : TFrom` will work if `TFrom` is a generic parameter of the outer class. Thus:

```
public class ExpressionTransformer<TFrom>
{
    // ...
    private class InnerExpressionTransformer<TTo>
        where TTo : TFrom
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The second method, should the inner parameter be necessary, is simply renaming one of the parameters, usually the inner one. Since this is a private class, it's easiest to change it there, such as to `TFromInner`.